# Foreach to Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, foreach

I have 2 ForEach loops and I'm trying to convert them into one Linq:

```
Dim result As Type = Nothing

For Each AssemblyItem As Reflection.Assembly In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies
    For Each typeItem As Type In AssemblyItem.GetTypes
        If myClass.FullName = typeItem.FullName Then
            result = typeItem
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not IsNothing(result) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

At the moment I have:

```
result = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .ForEach(Sub(x As Reflection.Assembly) 
                     x.GetTypes().ForEach(Sub(t As Type) 
                                              t.FullName = catalogEntity))
```

I also tried with another approach with no luck:

```
result = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Select(Sub(x) x.GetTypes()
        .Select(Function(y) y.GetType())
        .Where(Function(z) z.FullName.Equals(catalogEntity.FullName))).FirstOrDefault()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'action' of 'Public Shared Sub
>   ForEach(Of T)(array() As T, action As System.Action(Of T))'

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `ForEach` is a very un-LINQ (is that a word? is now) thing to do. It exists in `List<T>`, not in the LINQ extension methods. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @TimS. also tried the non-ForEach approach, but its giving me a null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in VB:

```
Dim result as Type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(Function(x) x.GetTypes()).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.FullName Is myClass.FullName)
```

And in C# (my native .NET language):

```
Type result = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == myClass.FullName);
```